# Nuxtjs full static build route not working in AWS Amplify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

Been deploying my nuxt2 app some days and I'm having some trouble.

When using the following flags within the nuxt.config.js:

`ssr: false, target: static`

The app dist folder gets generated with files relying entirely from JS logic to fetch data within the client side, and after the deployment the app works perfectly fine except that if the user doesn’t have javascript enabled on his client the app doesn’t work at all (furthermore, it’s not a good experience for SEO reasons)

When using the following flags:

`ssr: true, target: static`

The app dist folder gets generated with all the content available within the html source (good!) but when deployed the routing is messed up, the navigation between pages doesn’t work but the URLs do update.

I tried manually changing the URLs but it still fails.

Note: when starting a local server with the above dist everything works like a charm

This is my amplify build settings

`version: 1 frontend: phases: preBuild: commands: - yarn install build: commands: - echo "HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME" >> .env - yarn generate artifacts: # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory baseDirectory: dist files: - '**/*' cache: paths: - node_modules/**/*`

Unfortunately, I can’t provide the URL at this stage.

Comment: When deploying a Nuxtjs full static build to AWS Amplify, it is important to ensure that the URL rewriting is properly configured. The AWS Amplify documentation has a section on URL Rewriting which explains how to enable URL rewriting for static sites. Additionally, it is important to make sure that the correct files are being included in the build process. If the correct files are not included, then the routing may not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the redirect and rewrite rules in AWS Amplify. Removed all rewrite and redirects and now the site is working.